# Overlay raster layer on map in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I am trying to overlay a raster layer onto a map in ggplot. The raster layer contains likelihood surfaces for each time point from a satellite tag. I also want to set cumulative probabilities(95%, 75%, 50%) on the raster layer.

I have figured out how to show the raster layer on the ggplot map, but the coordinates are not aligned with one another. I tried making each have the same projection but it does not seem to be working... I want them both to fit the boundaries of my model (xmin = 149, xmax = 154, ymin = -14, ymax = -8.75

Attached is my r code and the figure result:

```
#load data
ncname <- "152724-13-GPE3"
ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)

StackedObject<-stack("152724-13-GPE3.nc", varname = "monthly_residency_distributions")
MergedObject<-overlay(StackedObject,fun=mean ) 
MergedObject[is.na(MergedObject)]<-0 
Boundaries<-extent(c(149, 154, -14, -8.75)) 
ExtendedObject<-extend(MergedObject, Boundaries) 
Raster.big<-raster(ncol=1200,nrow=900,ext=Boundaries) 
Raster.HR<-resample(x=ExtendedObject, y=Raster.big, method="bilinear") 
Raster.HR@data@values<- Raster.HR@data@values/sum(Raster.HR@data@values) 
RasterVals<-sort(Raster.HR@data@values)
Raster.breaks <- c(RasterVals[max(which(cumsum(RasterVals)<= 0.05 ))], RasterVals[max(which(cumsum(RasterVals)<= 0.25 ))], RasterVals[max(which(cumsum(RasterVals)<= 0.50 ))], 1)
Raster.cols<-colorRampPalette(c("yellow","orange","red"))
RasterCols<- c(Raster.cols(3))

#Create Map
shape2 <- readOGR(dsn = "/Users/shannonmurphy/Desktop/PNG_adm/PNG_adm1.shp", layer = "PNG_adm1")
map<- crop(shape2, extent(149, 154, -14, -8.75))
projection(map)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = "black", size = 0.25) + coord_map()

projection(Raster.HR)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

#plot raster and ggplot 

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(p)
par(mfrow=c(1,1), new = TRUE)
plot(Raster.HR, col=RasterCols, breaks=Raster.breaks, legend = NULL, bbox(map))
```

[image]

Please let me know if there is another package/line of code I should be using to do this! Appreciate any help

Comment: Hi, I just noticed you rejected my edit. The only change was inlining that image. Is the current state ok for you?

Comment: Hi @yacc sorry I misread, I thought you were saying to delete it. Feel free to edit again, sorry about that.

Comment: Never mind. It's common to edit questions like that, because 1) new users don't have privilege to inline images (funny, but it's a spam prevention I think), and 2) edit-improving posts is somewhat rewarded. I'm going for strunk-and-white medal for instance. This means 80 edits to get a silver medal. :) It's a fun thing about this medals, I don't know, but it's fun. Ok then.

Comment: You can use `rasterVis::gplot` to directly add a raster in a ggplot.

Comment: @SébastienRochette I tried that, but am having a hard time adding the other raster parameters I want, such as the 50, 75, 95% likelihood and color scheme that goes with that. I am also a little unclear on what function to use exactly from the rasterVis package to add this raster layer to the ggplot.

Answer (score 12):

Ok I understand. You want to plot multiple raster layers on the ggplot or you want that the raster object is over your background polygon object. The problem with `rasterVis::gplot` is that it directly plot the raster and does not allow to add another one under or over. You remind me that I already had this need and modified function `gplot` to retrieve the data as a tibble so that you can then play with it as much as you want with `dplyr` and then `ggplot2`. Thanks for the reminder, I added it in my current github library for later use!
Let's use a reproducible example to show this function:

## Create datasets

- Create a map of the world as a `Raster` to be use as background Raster map
- Create a raster of data, here a distance from a point (limited to a maximum distance)

The code:

```
library(raster)

# Get world map
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
# Transform World as raster
r <- raster(wrld_simpl, res = 1)
wrld_r <- rasterize(wrld_simpl, r)

# Lets create a raster of data
pt1 <- matrix(c(100,0), ncol = 2)
dist1 <- distanceFromPoints(r, pt1)
values(dist1)[values(dist1) > 5e6] <- NA
plot(dist1)

# Plot both
plot(wrld_r, col = "grey")
plot(dist1, add = TRUE)
```

[image: Both Raster data on classic plot]

## Function to extract (part of) raster values and transform as a tibble

```
#' Transform raster as data.frame to be later used with ggplot
#' Modified from rasterVis::gplot
#'
#' @param x A Raster* object
#' @param maxpixels Maximum number of pixels to use
#'
#' @details rasterVis::gplot is nice to plot a raster in a ggplot but
#' if you want to plot different rasters on the same plot, you are stuck.
#' If you want to add other information or transform your raster as a
#' category raster, you can not do it. With `SDMSelect::gplot_data`, you retrieve your
#' raster as a tibble that can be modified as wanted using `dplyr` and
#' then plot in `ggplot` using `geom_tile`.
#' If Raster has levels, they will be joined to the final tibble.
#'
#' @export

gplot_data <- function(x, maxpixels = 50000)  {
  x <- raster::sampleRegular(x, maxpixels, asRaster = TRUE)
  coords <- raster::xyFromCell(x, seq_len(raster::ncell(x)))
  ## Extract values
  dat <- utils::stack(as.data.frame(raster::getValues(x))) 
  names(dat) <- c('value', 'variable')

  dat <- dplyr::as.tbl(data.frame(coords, dat))

  if (!is.null(levels(x))) {
    dat <- dplyr::left_join(dat, levels(x)[[1]], 
                            by = c("value" = "ID"))
  }
  dat
}
```

## Plot multiple rasters in ggplot

You can use `gplot_data` to transform any raster as a tibble. You are then able to add any modification using `dplyr` and plot on `ggplot` with `geom_tile`. The interesting point is that you can use `geom_tile` as many time as you want with different raster data, provided that `fill` option is comparable. Otherwise, you can use the trick below to remove `NA` values in the background raster map and use a unique `fill` colour.

```
# With gplot_data
library(ggplot2)

# Transform rasters as data frame 
gplot_wrld_r <- gplot_data(wrld_r)
gplot_dist1 <- gplot_data(dist1)

# To define a unique fill colour for the world map,
# you need to remove NA values in gplot_wrld_r which 
# can be done with dplyr::filter
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = dplyr::filter(gplot_wrld_r, !is.na(value)), 
            aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "grey20") +
  geom_tile(data = gplot_dist1, 
            aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient("Distance",
                      low = 'yellow', high = 'blue',
                      na.value = NA) +
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image: Multiple raster on the same ggplot]

## Plot raster over polygons

Of course, with a background map as a polygon object, this trick also let you add your raster over it:

```
wrld_simpl_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(wrld_simpl)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = wrld_simpl_sf, fill = "grey20",
          colour = "white", size = 0.2) +
  geom_tile(data = gplot_dist1, 
            aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient("Distance",
                      low = 'yellow', high = 'blue',
                      na.value = NA)
```

[image: Raster over polygons in ggplot]

EDIT: `gplot_data` is now in this simple R package: https://github.com/statnmap/cartomisc